# How to fix error 501 while using yocto build tool?

Tags: https, linux-kernel, embedded, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to bitbake linux-imx with following command in my source recipe:-
KERNEL_SRC ?= "https://username:passsord@vcs.rafi.cloud/scm/f-pep2219002-akka/evalkit-powerecu-2.git;protocol=https"

I am receivin the following error:-

> Resolving vcs.rafi.cloud (vcs.rafi.cloud)... 192.81.121.25 Connecting
>   to vcs.rafi.cloud (vcs.rafi.cloud)|192.81.121.25|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 501  2019-09-16 13:05:48 ERROR
>   501: (no description)

What is the reason for this error and how to resolve it ?

Comment: I am able to download the repo with the same URL in terminal

Comment: Linux repositories are usually git, but the `KERNEL_SRC` variable (which I presume is evaluated in `SRC_URI`) says otherwise. If this is the case you may need to take a look at [this](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.8/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#git-fetcher) and [this](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-SRC_URI).

Comment: when using git, you must start with `git://` even if it is `https` protocol

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but based on a quick look at the code I believe this might work:

```
git://vcs.rafi.cloud/scm/f-pep2219002-akka/evalkit-powerecu-2.git;protocol=https;user=username:password
```